# How to repeat value in middle of loop?

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, jupyter-notebook

When the loop reaches the max value I want to print it again and again for the number in max value, i.e. if max = 5 I want to reach the loop till 5 and the print 5 for 5 times and the continue in reverse order.

```
max=10
if max >= 0: 
    for i in range(1, max): 
        print(i) 
        if i == max: 
            for _ in range(5): 
                print(i) 
    else:
        print("x") 
        for i in range(max, 0, -1): 
            print(i)
```

This is code I tried but it doesn't seem to repeat the max values

Comment: You will need to have `print(max)` somewhere in your code. Also is sounds like you just need three `for` loops, one after another.

Comment: Or you could use a `while` loop and set the exit and iteration conditions manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

is this what you are looking?

```
max=5
if max >= 0: 
    for i in range(1, max+1): 
        print(i) 
        if i == max: 
            for i in range(max): 
                print(max) 
    else:
        print("x") 
        for i in range(max, 0, -1): 
            print(i)
```

Comment: The `else` statement is useless there, maybe consider removing it, for clarity purpose.